# Service + BroadcastReceiver pair vs Loader/AsyncTaskLoader

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver, loader

Are there situations where an AsyncTaskLoader is more appropriate than a Service+BroadcastReceiver pair? Or is a loader redundant in that sense? And in case of a cursor, is it not always better to use a Service+ContentProvider pair instead of a loader? I am trying to see whether Loaders are necessary to android or whether it's something that is just there but whose usefulness is at best redundant. So basically, are they important and in what cases are they best suited for the job than any other object?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Loaders provide caching. It's usually easier to work with the UI (especially screen rotations) when using loaders because the `LoaderManager` is connected to the activity, i.e. there is no issue with memory leaks.

Consider this case: You start loading data and then you rotate your device. Activity will be recreated in this case. How would you handle that with `Service` + `BroadcastReceiver`? You will have to ask your service to give you data after rotation and it will send it through broadcast intent which assumes you'll have to serialize your data first.. e.g. into `Parcelable`. If you need a collection of objects you'll probably have to bind to the service first.
If you used loaders, after screen rotation `onLoadFinished` would be called automatically and data would be taken from cache. I think this is much more convenient than `Service`.

Loaders support content observers. You can create content observers that will monitor any changes in underlying data and trigger loaders when needed. This is also very powerful mechanism that allows you to keep your data up-to-date. You can implement this manually when using a `Service` but still I think it's more convenient to use loaders here.

To answer your question, no, loaders are not necessary, you can always replace them with some other solution. But they are very convenient for loading data because their lifecycle is tied to UI components and they provide some useful API out of box.

Comment: `ContentProvider`s are wrappers around a database, you can use them with loaders or without them.. By default they work on a background thread, so you will need to implement threading. Loaders solve the threading issue for queries, but for insert update and delete you will need your own threading anyway, e.g. `AsyncQueryHandler`. I prefer using both `Loaders` and `ContentProvider` because they work really good together.

Comment: I'm sorry, I confused you, of course I mean that `ContentProvider` works on a UI thread by default and that's why you need to implement threading. Otherwise it doesn't make sense :) Sorry.